# Playing with null and zero values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a variable which can hold value as zero or null.

Ex:-

```
var temp = 0;

if(temp){ // if temp is zero do some work if null go in else
// Do some work
} else {

}
```

How i can check this without using temp === 0 as 0 is false.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What's wrong with ===?

Comment: You can try `temp == null`. This will check `undefined` and `null`

Comment: 0 being a false value doesn't seem like a reason (good or otherwise) not to use `temp === 0`.

Comment: 0 is not false, it is evaluated as false: `0==false` while `0!==false`

Comment: Nothing just wanted to know any other way like null >= 0 kind of.

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong with ===?
>
> Nothing just wanted to know any other way like null >= 0 kind of.

In that case, you can do:

```
if (temp === 0 || temp > 0)...
```

That would replace your `>=` not-null idea.

Of course, that replaces `"if temp is zero do some work if null go in else"` with `"if temp is zero or higher do some work if null go in else"` (really not clear in your question)

Answer (score 1):

You could explicit test if the value is not strict equal to `null`.

```
if (temp !== null) {
    // temp is not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp=null;
if(temp===null){
 //temp is null
}
else{
 if(temp===0){
 //temp is 0
 }
 }
```

do this way..

as you need, if temp===0 go to first if and if temp===null go to second if, i guess this is what you want vaibhav.

Comment: *do this way..* Why?? Please explain what and why have you changed?

Comment: he wants to have  two if functions.. one for temp===0 and another for temp===null, so i have just make it ..

Comment: Please add explanation in your answer.